# Create List and Select List Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create list of letters (A B C D ...) for phonebook and I want to select for example A from list. How can I do this.
I want to see in Repeater (Starting of Name). For example If I select M ,I want to see Murat, Marc, Maria etc. in repeater.

C#: I  tried use BulletedList but I cant.

```
char[] alpha = "ABCÇDEFGHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ".ToCharArray();


for (int i = 0; i <alpha.Length; i++)
{                
   ListItem listItem = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(alpha[i]));
   listItem.Attributes.Add("value", Convert.ToString(i));
   telList.Items.Add(listItem);
}
Repeater:
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTable">
<HeaderTemplate>
   <table title="TELEPHONEBOOK" id="table" style="float: left" class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server" id="trId">
      <td><%#Eval("Name")%></td>
      <td><%#Eval("Sur_Name")%></td>
      <td><%#Eval("Telephone1")%></td>
      <td><%#Eval("Mobile1")%></td>
      <td><%#Eval("Gender")%></td>
      <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' CommandName="Upd" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-icon.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" ID="btnUpdate" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" /></td>
      <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' CommandName="Del" ImageUrl="~/Images/sprite.png" Height="25px" Width="25px" ID="btnDelete" OnClientClick="Delete" CssClass="opener" ToolTip="dialog" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" /></td>
     /*<%--<td><asp:ImageButton runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' CommandName="Add" ImageUrl="~/Images/add.png" Height="25px" Width="25px"   /></td>--%>*/
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
  </FooterTemplate>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler to your BulletedList, and bind the repeater with the items whose FirstName start with the clicked value of the BulletedList. Example:

```
protected void telList_OnClick(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    var contacts = new List<string> { "aa", "ab", "cccc" };
    char clickeckChar = "ABCÇDEFGHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ"[e.Index];

    rptTable.DataSource = 
        contacts
        .Where(contact => contact.ToUpper().StartsWith(clickeckChar.ToString().ToUpper()))
        .ToList();
    rptTable.DataBind();
}
```

Also, I don't know where you are getting your contacts from, so I just created a list of strings for the sake of the example. Each time a link from the BulltedList is clicked, the contacts data is filtered according to the letter clicked and the repeater is bound again. Your BulletedList must have its DisplayMode set to LinkButton, or else you can't do this.

Comment: Do you know or have some exaple for this? Can I use java script ?